# How to reveal a list over a token of sentence using tableview in javafx?

Tags: list, javafx, tableview, token

I have to find synonyms of words of a text statement in tableview. Those words which have their synonyms stored in database will be highlighted and on clicking at that word, a list or combobox will be displayed showing the synonyms of that word.But i am not getting how a list will be revealed on a token of a sentence?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Show us the code you already have.

Comment: I didn't find any such code to work on. I separated the sentence stored in database into tokens and getting no idea how to apply a list on it.